# Загрузка медиафайлов

Tags: веб-служба

Суть проблемы: есть сайт, на котором нужно организовать загрузку медиаматериалов: видео, музыка, картинки и т.п. для зарегистрированных пользователей. Но сам хостинг ограничивает место на жёстком диске. Увидел, что хешкод пользуется imgur.com для хранения картинок. Причём мне, как пользователю хешкода, регистрироваться на imgur не надо, что есть очень хорошо.

Как можно реализовать подобное хранение медиафайлов? Как долго будут они храниться (в том же самом imgur)? Какие есть альтернативы? Какое максимальное количество файлов можно загружать в час, например? (нужно как можно больше)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никто вам просто так под медиа файлы не даст много протранства!

1. Технически реализовать не сложно.
2. Однозначно нужен VPS или лучше VDS.
3. А нужно ли оно Вам?

Полностью опишу п. 3

1. Реализация рекламы в сети которая потребует множества затрат.
2. Пройдет несколько лет пока Ваш ресурс начнет окупать потраченные финансы.
3. От сюда исходит факт что нужен хороший БП(бизнес план) и инвестор который этот БП будет поддерживать своими финансовыми гарантиями.

Из прочитанного мною вопроса и перечисленного мной выше, шансы открыть Вам свой медиа ресурс рвны 0.

Нужно ли оно Вам? Найдите идею по гениальнее и привлекайте инвесторов к более гениальной идее чем к медиа ресурсу которых полно в инете! Например украинский ex.ua нет времени ожидания, нет капчи, нет ограничения скорости, нет гемороя, пришел и скачал.

Comment: МЕДИА РЕСУРС открывать не надо. Просто, например, сайт, в котором обучают видеомонтажу, фотомонтажу и т.п. САМИ УРОКИ, статьи будут на сайте, а примеры (видео, аудио и т.д.) невозможно хранить на таком хостинге, а где-то их хранить надо, так ГДЕ?

Comment: могу посоветывать ex.ua. ограничений на хранение нет! поюзайте сайт, посмотрите как там все раализовано, поставьте на свой сайт такие же медиа плееры как там и будет вам счастье. там достаточно тематических рубрик из которых ваши файлы не удалят никогда если сами видео и аудио уроки не нарушают авторских прав.

Comment: к тому же добавлю что ссылки на файлы прямые, и к стате нет ограничений на размер файла, хоть 25 гектар.

Comment: Ваша ссылка редирекнула меня на fex.net и там такое сообщение: "Objects which are not used for longer than 30 days can be deleted by the system." - что не есть хорошо :(